# Issue with InMobi Payment to PayPal

Tags: paypal, inmobi, applovin

I've recently encountered an issue with the payment from InMobi to PayPal. Here are the details of the situation:

On the InMobi platform, in the payouts section, this is what I am seeing:

| DATE | AMOUNT | ACCOUNT/MODE | REMARKS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 31 Oct 2023 | $360.64 | Paypal-null | EARNINGS THROUGH AUGUST-2023 |

From what I see in the table, it would appear that the payment was made, but I did not receive anything in my Paypal account.

I've opened tickets with InMobi support, but so far, I've only received generic responses like: "Your query has been escalated to the concerned team. We are working with relevant teams to provide a quick resolution and will get back to you at the earliest."

I've verified my PayPal account, and it seems to be in good standing. What might be happening?

Comment: Could you edit the post to explain how these things are different from what you expect? Does the transaction fail?

Comment: What is the significance of the "REMARKS" column?